# using custom test on geom_signif()

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I made a custom test (mermaid.test) so that I can use it instead of default t.test in geom_signif() as part of my plots. I've been using the help of chatGPT but it's barely helping at this point :(

**mermaid test:**
The intention is basically do a shapiro test on both groups to check if they follow a normal distribution. In case both of them do, then I want to perform a t.test. Otherwise, I go with a wilcoxon.

```
mermaid.test <- function(group1, group2) {
  sp_group1 <- shapiro.test(group1)$p.value
  sp_group2 <- shapiro.test(group2)$p.value
  if (sp_group1 > 0.05 && sp_group2 > 0.05) {
    t_test_result <- t.test(group1, group2)
    p_value <- t_test_result$p.value
  } else {
    wilcox_result <- wilcox.test(group1, group2)
    p_value <- wilcox_result$p.value
  }
  result <- list(p.value = p_value)
  return(result)
```

**My plot:**

```
ggplot(data = filtered_data, aes(x = group, y = p21, fill = treatment)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "col", color = "black", width = 0.9, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_se, geom = "errorbar", width = 0.1, position = position_dodge(0.9)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = sex), position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 0.9, jitter.width = 0.1)) +
  scale_fill_brewer("BuPu") +
  theme_prism() +
  geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("WT CTRL", "WT 24H"),
                                 c("KO CTRL", "KO 24H")),
              map_signif_level = TRUE, textsize = 3, vjust = -0.25, step_increase = 0.2) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = .5),
        axis.title.x = element_blank())
```

If you come up with any other better way, have a say. I have lots of graphs to plot and I'm looking for the fastest and most automated way to generate them.

Thanks a lot :)))

Lexie